# Populate Knockout's observable array from Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement error handling in ASP.NET so that if there is an error the user will get the error message, then be able to go back and have the previous state restored. I'm using ASP.NET Core and Knockout (not my implementation). I want to update "signerFields" with the model from the server (Model.SignersJson). How would I do this?

Signer.js

```
function SignerViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.signerFields = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.guarantorFields = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.companyGuarantorFields = ko.observableArray([]);

...
```

Signer.cshtml

```
<div data-bind="foreach: signerFields, visible: signerFields().length > 0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div>
                                @*Header Company signers section*@
                                <div class="row" data-bind="visible: isCompany() && !anySigner() && !isInvitation()" style="display: none">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <b>FullName</b>
                                    </div>
                                    @*<div class="col-lg-3">
                                            <b>LastName </b>
                                        </div>*@
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <b>Role </b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <b>Contact_Information</b>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        ...


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/Signer.js"></script>
    var serverSigners = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SignersJson)));
    var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverSigners);

    var viewModel = new SignerViewModel();
    viewModel.signerFields(observableData); // <-- How?
}
```

I get no error messages, nothing.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What is not working?

Comment: @ChrisPratt When I refresh the page I want the data to be populated into the observable array. The data comes from the server (Model.SignersJson). How can I push data (Model.SignersJson) to the Knockout's viewModel's observable array (self.signerFields)?

Comment: It *should* work exactly as you're doing it, assuming that the bindings match what it's the in JSON (which we can't see). Therefore, the question is *have you actually tried it?* And, then, if you have, what's not working.

Comment: I changed the code to map to observable data, but I get no error messages or anything.

Comment: Well, you won't get an error message as long as you pass it an array, since that's all it cares about. It's likely an issue with the JSON not matching your bindings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of unknowns with this one, but here is a working example using the information we have at hand.  One thing I noticed was when creating this sample was that I assumed the data comming from Razor was in an array. and when the array is passed into the mapping component it comes out as an observable array.  This meant that the data going into the signerFields was probably not what you were expecting and ended up having an observableArray with one object which itself was an observable array.  Adding round brackets to  `observableData()`  means that you get the data out of the observable and you can then pass it into the signerFields as an array of objects.

Hope that made sense.

```js
function SignerViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.signerFields = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.guarantorFields = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.companyGuarantorFields = ko.observableArray([]);
  
}
var serverSigners = [{'fullname':'Test Name', 'lastName': 'Name', 'role': 'Test Role', 'contactInformation': '123 Seasame Street NY, US', 'isCompany': true, 'anySigner': false, 'isInvitation': false}];
var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverSigners);
var viewModel = new SignerViewModel();

viewModel.signerFields(observableData());


ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: signerFields, visible: signerFields().length > 0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div>
        <div class="row" data-bind="visible: isCompany() && !anySigner() && !isInvitation()">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <b>FullName: </b><span data-bind="text: fullname"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <b>LastName: </b><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4"> 
            <b>Role: </b><span data-bind="text: role"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <b>Contact Information: </b><span data-bind="text: contactInformation"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```